# MySQL timeout in powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell, timeout

I have a MySQL DB setup on my Windows laptop. I'm using a powershell script to connect/query/input to the DB. I have a query I'm trying to run, I can run it in the MySQL Workbench currently it takes 31.032 sec to run and returns 3 rows.

```
SELECT puz1.sudoku9x9_id, puz1.difficulty, puz2.sudoku9x9_id, puz2.difficulty 
    FROM sudoku9x9 as puz1 
    INNER JOIN sudoku9x9 as puz2 
        WHERE  
            puz1.clue_9 = puz2.clue_1 AND puz1.region_9 = puz2.region_1 AND 
            puz1.difficulty/puz2.difficulty BETWEEN .84 AND 1.19 AND 
            NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM samurai2x AS a 
            WHERE 
                a.puz1_id = puz1.sudoku9x9_id AND a.puz2_id = puz2.sudoku9x9_id)
```

Powershell Script

```
$samurai2x = "SELECT puz1.sudoku9x9_id, puz1.difficulty, puz2.sudoku9x9_id, puz2.difficulty FROM sudoku9x9 as puz1 INNER JOIN sudoku9x9 as puz2 WHERE puz1.clue_9 = puz2.clue_1 AND puz1.region_9 = puz2.region_1 AND puz1.difficulty/puz2.difficulty BETWEEN .84 AND 1.19 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM samurai2x AS a WHERE a.puz1_id = puz1.sudoku9x9_id AND a.puz2_id = puz2.sudoku9x9_id) LIMIT 1"

Invoke-MySqlQuery -Query $samurai2x | ForEach {
    $diff = ([INT]$_.'difficulty' + [INT]$_.'difficulty1') / 2
    Invoke-MySqlQuery -Query "INSERT INTO samurai2x(difficulty, puz1_id, puz2_id) VALUES ('$diff', '$($_.'sudoku9x9_id')', '$($_.'sudoku9x9_id1')')"
}
```

When I run the powershell script, it times out. So I looked into changing the timeout options. I first ran

```
SET GLOBAL connect_timeout=31536000;
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=2147483;
SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=31536000;
```

The numbers are the max allowed from the MySQL documentation. That did not cut it! So I edited the my.ini file and added

```
[mysqld]

connect_timeout=31536000
wait_timeout=2147483
interactive_timeout=31536000
```

I restarted the MySQL service. Still the same issue!

When the script connects to the DB it displays

```
ServerThread      : 26
DataSource        : localhost
ConnectionTimeout : 15
Database          : sudoku
UseCompression    : False
State             : Open
ServerVersion     : 5.7.17-log
ConnectionString  : server=localhost;port=3306;user id=root;database=sudoku
IsPasswordExpired : False
Site              : 
Container         :
```

The ConnectionTimeout has always displayed 15 prior to editing the timeout and after every attempt.

What am I missing here guys? Thanks in advance for the help.

---

### EDIT

```
# Set MySQL connection info
$username = "root"
$password = cat D:\Sudoku\mysecurestring.txt | convertto-securestring
$dbcred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
         -argumentlist $username, $password

# Connect to MySQL server
Connect-MySqlServer -Credential $dbcred -ComputerName localhost -Database sudoku
```

I'm connecting to the DB based on the steps at this site: [Querying MySQL Databases with PowerShell](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/03/02/querying-mysql-databases.aspx)

---

EDIT

At the bottom is the modified function. I put a comment "Added" above each new line.

New Connection Line

```
Connect-MySqlServer -Credential $dbcred -ComputerName localhost -Database sudoku -CommandTimeOut 600 -ConnectionTimeOut 25
```

New Connection Output

```
ServerThread      : 23
DataSource        : localhost
ConnectionTimeout : 25
Database          : sudoku
UseCompression    : False
State             : Open
ServerVersion     : 5.7.17-log
ConnectionString  : server=localhost;port=3306;user id=root;database=sudoku;defaultcommandtimeout=600;connectiontimeout=25
IsPasswordExpired : False
Site              : 
Container         :
```

Modified Function

```
function Connect-MySqlServer
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Connect to a MySQL Server
    .DESCRIPTION
        This function will establish a connection to a local or remote instance of 
        a MySQL Server. By default it will connect to the local instance on the 
        default port.
    .PARAMETER ComputerName
        The name of the remote computer to connect to, otherwise default to localhost
    .PARAMETER Port
        By default this is 3306, otherwise specify the correct value
    .PARAMETER Credential
        Typically this may be your root credentials, or to work in a specific 
        database the credentials with appropriate rights to do work in that database.
    .PARAMETER Database
        An optional parameter that will connect you to a specific database
    .PARAMETER TimeOut
        By default timeout is set to 15 seconds
    .EXAMPLE
        Connect-MySqlServer -Credential (Get-Credential)

        cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
        Supply values for the following parameters:
        Credential


        ServerThread      : 2
        DataSource        : localhost
        ConnectionTimeout : 15
        Database          :
        UseCompression    : False
        State             : Open
        ServerVersion     : 5.6.22-log
        ConnectionString  : server=localhost;port=3306;User Id=root
        IsPasswordExpired : False
        Site              :
        Container         :

        Description
        -----------
        Connect to the local mysql instance as root. This example uses the 
        Get-Credential cmdlet to prompt for username and password.
    .EXAMPLE
        Connect-MySqlServer -ComputerName db.company.com -Credential (Get-Credential)

        cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
        Supply values for the following parameters:
        Credential


        ServerThread      : 2
        DataSource        : db.company.com
        ConnectionTimeout : 15
        Database          :
        UseCompression    : False
        State             : Open
        ServerVersion     : 5.6.22-log
        ConnectionString  : server=db.company.com;port=3306;User Id=root
        IsPasswordExpired : False
        Site              :
        Container         :

        Description
        -----------
        Connect to a remote mysql instance as root. This example uses the 
        Get-Credential cmdlet to prompt for username and password.
    .NOTES
        FunctionName : Connect-MySqlServer
        Created by   : jspatton
        Date Coded   : 02/11/2015 09:19:10
    .LINK
        https://github.com/jeffpatton1971/mod-posh/wiki/MySQL#Connect-MySqlServer
    #>
    [OutputType('MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection')]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [pscredential]$Credential,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateScript({ Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Quiet -Count 1 })]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [int]$Port = 3306,

        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Database,

        # Added
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [int]$CommandTimeOut = 15,

        # Added
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [int]$ConnectionTimeOut = 20
    )
    begin
    {
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

        if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Database')) {
            $connectionString = 'server={0};port={1};uid={2};pwd={3};database={4};' -f $ComputerName,$Port,$Credential.UserName, $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password,$Database
        }
        else
        {
            $connectionString = 'server={0};port={1};uid={2};pwd={3};' -f $ComputerName, $Port, $Credential.UserName, $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
        }
        # Added
        $connectionString = $connectionString + "default command timeout=$CommandTimeOut; Connection Timeout=$ConnectionTimeOut;"
    }
    process
    {
        try
        {
            [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection]$conn = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($connectionString)
            $conn.Open()
            $Global:MySQLConnection = $conn
            if ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Database')) {
                $null =  New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand("USE $Database", $conn)
            }
            $conn
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception.Message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the portion of the Powershell script where you create and open the connection to your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `default command timeout=60;` to the connection string in your Powershell script.

You may also want to set the `CommandTimeout` property of the [`MySqlCommand`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_CommandTimeout.htm) object.

Comment: I'm using the the method described on the site below. I'm trying to figure out how to impliment your advice. It looks like your connecting a different way than I am. I don't mind switching methods, if we are. How are you connecting? I put an edit on my post with the connection code in my script.
https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/03/02/querying-mysql-databases.aspx

Comment: I added the string to the module. It's not perfect, the display still shows 15 on connect.  I added the timeout as a variable. It registers and changes the timeout. Need to figure out what I'm missing and I'll fork the repository in the hopes they add it to the master. Thank you for the pointer in the right direction!

Comment: @IanManseau connect timeout is not the same as command timeout. I'm on mobile at the moment so I'll have to look at that module later to see if it allows setting a command timeout.

Comment: Ha, I did not even see that. That's what I get for staying up all hours into the night on something. I added a parameter for both because well why not. My OCD is going nuts, the output shows the new strings with no spaces, and I can't find out why.

Comment: @IanManseau Are you submitting a PR to Adam Bertram to add those parameters to `New-MySqlConnection`?

Comment: Yes, submitted and accepted. Thanks again for the help!